# hardware upgrade

Tags: windows

Can any one explain this

"My feiend is using a Windows xP O.S. & a 2x2gb=4gb RAM but on the DXDIAG it onlt shows 3gb"

Also

"I have Windows Vista 64 bit & 2 gb RAM, So is it OK if  I get another 2 gb RAM, I mean It
wouldnt show only 3 gb insted of 4 gb"

Comment: Multiple duplicates - http://superuser.com/questions/15900/4gb-memory-seen-as-3gb-in-bios

http://superuser.com/questions/30425/i-have-4gb-of-ram-installed-but-only-2gb-are-useble

http://superuser.com/questions/17827/using-3-gb-ram-in-vista-windows732-bit

http://superuser.com/questions/27086/windows-xp-and-ram-3-5gb

http://superuser.com/questions/27006/how-to-check-ram-size-without-looking-at-motherboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK... It could be a few things, but the most common thing is...

Your friend either has the 32 bit edition of Windows which can only see ~3GBs of memory, or he has the 64bit edition, but 1GB is reserved for graphics.

If you have the 64bit edition, you should not have a problem seeing the full 4GBs unless again, you have memory reserved for your graphics card.